# Retrieving synonyms from an ontology

Tags: java, performance, iterator

My  question is about my Ontology which retrieves *synonyms*
    from the ontology by using *isSynonymOf* object property. (Note that
    my Ontology file is *260 kb* and expected to become *500kb*). I am using
    following code to retrieve the synonyms. The performance in terms of
    response time is very low. It takes a lot of time(minutes) to
    display synonyms. How can i improve it?
Note: The problem looks like in similarity algorithm and iterator.

Here is My full Code

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.jena.ontology.Individual;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.SymmetricProperty;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.NodeIterator;
import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;

import xyzWordAnalyzer;
import cde.model.SimilarityModel;
public class ontologyConnector
{
    private static ontologyConnector    instance;
    private static OntModel             ontModel;
    protected static final Sring        SOURCE_FILE = "http://abc.owl";
    protected static final String       NS          = SOURCE_FILE + "abc";

    public static synchronized ontologyConnector getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new ontologyConnector();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public ontologyConnector()
    {
        ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(SOURCE_FILE);
        ontModel.read(in, "");
    }

    public ArrayList<SimilarityModel> getRelatums(String keyword)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        keyword = keyword.replaceAll(" ", "_");

        SymmetricProperty isSynonymOf = ontModel.getSymmetricProperty("http://www.semanticweb.org/abc#isSynonymOf");

        Iterator<Individual> iterInd = ontModel.listIndividuals();
        while (iterInd.hasNext())
        {
            Individual ind = iterInd.next();
            if (ind.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase(keyword))
            {
                NodeIterator iterVal = ind.listPropertyValues(isSynonymOf);
                while (iterVal.hasNext())
                {
                    list.add(iterVal.nextNode().asResource().getLocalName().toString().replace("_", " "));
                }
            }
        }

      list = removeDuplicationfromList(keyword, list);

    // list.remove(keyword);

        ArrayList<SimilarityModel> simList = new ArrayList<SimilarityModel>();

        Double tot = (double) 0;
        WordAnalyzer wa = new WordAnalyzer();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Double tmpDouble = wa.getSimilarity(keyword.toLowerCase(), 
          list.get(i));

            int tmp = 0;
            if (Double.isNaN(tmpDouble)) {
                // tmpDouble = (double) -200;
                tmp = -200;
            } else {
                tmpDouble *= 100;
                tot += tmpDouble;
                tmp = tmpDouble.intValue();
            }

            SimilarityModel simModel = new SimilarityModel(list.get(i), tmp);
            simList.add(simModel);
        }

        Double avg = tot / simList.size();
        if (!Double.isNaN(avg)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < simList.size(); i++) {
                if (simList.get(i).getSimilarity() == -200) {
                    simList.get(i).setSimilarity(avg.intValue());
                }
            }
        }

        return simList;
    }

     private ArrayList<String> removeDuplicationfromList(String str, 
      ArrayList<String> list) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
          }
         return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can I download the executable project? Where does the `OntModel` class come from? Why don't you follow the Java naming conventions ? Who is forcing you into the ugly `Iterator` API instead of the nice and modern `for (obj : iterable)`? You should answer all these questions in your post. Just [edit] it.

Comment: I agree that the question needs to be improved, e. g. with an explanation of what it does. But can anyone explain to me how the downvotes are justified? To me, this does not look like a bad question, and neither an off-topic one.

Comment: Also, @RolandIllig, aren't the ugly Iterator API and the bad naming style what the review answers should be about, rather than being answered by the asker?

Comment: @RaimundKrämer my ontology  retrieves related terms when i search a keyword. Primarily, my code do well but when my ontology is growing, then retriving process becomes slow. That is the problem what i am facing with above mentioned code.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer If you could answer this question, that would be great. I think that most people would say that there is not enough information here to explain why there is a performance problem.

Comment: @Tolga Please add the explanation to the question by editing it, rather than in a comment. Also, the explanation should go into more detail, and it would help a lot if you would add more code to your question, for example the classes `OntModel`, `SymmetricProperty` and others. There is a lot in your code that is worth a review, but the performance problem lies most likely somewhere else in your code, if at all.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer I have edited my question and add full code with out put.

Comment: @200_success pls have a look on my code again

Comment: @Tolga It is good that you added more code, but please do not edit your code (except from adding to it) according to suggestions made in answers or comments. Changing the class name from `ontologyConnector` to `OntologyConnector` not only invalidates my answer, but it creates errors in your code since you did not change it in all places. Please edit your question to include the **(complete) original code** again, but **without changing the code to include suggestions from answers**.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer The problem lies in similarity algorithm or iterator . But could find way to fix it

Answer (score 3):

### Design

You have implemented the class as a singleton, but made the constructor public. That makes the use of the singleton pattern kind of useless. Since you want the class to only be instantiated once, which is inside the class itself, you should make it `private`.

---

```
public ArrayList<SimilarityModel> getRelatums(String keyword)
```

Especially in the API of a class, i. e. its public members like this method, you should use interfaces or abstract types, rather than specific implementations. If you replace `ArrayList<SimilarityModel>` with `List<SimilarityModel>`, you can use any implementation of `List` that you like, without having to change many parts of your code.

### Style

The Java convention for class names is `UpperCamelCase`. `ontologyConnector` should be `OntologyConnector`.

---

Your names are not only inconsistent in capitalization, but also abbreviation. `OntModel` should be written out as `OntologyModel`, to fit with `OntologyConnector` but also because abbreviations sometimes force the reader to guess what it means and thus destroy the code's readability.

---

```
public ArrayList<SimilarityModel> getRelatums(String keyword)
```

The return type suggests that the method returns a collection of `SimilarityModel`s, but is named `getRelatums`. It should be called `getSimilarityModels`, if that's what it is actually doing. If not, then the name of the type `SimilarityModel` might be chosen badly.

---

*As others have already pointed out in the comments, in order to get help with the performance problem you need to add more information and code (e. g. the classes `OntModel` and `SymmetricProperty`). However in my opinion there is still a lot you can improve in the already available code to make it worth a review. Please add more code to get further suggestions as performance improvements.*